# Libraries for OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, libraries, deprecated

I've read around that there is a lot of deprecation going on with OpenGL. I've heard this has to do with the implementation of shaders. Are there any libraries that are affected by this deprecation? 
 seems to suggest SFML, GLFW, and SDL as up to date libraries. 
Do other libraries such as glew or glut have problems with the deprecation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) is the utility library which contains helpful methods mostly related to GUI. GLUT is outdated for something like 10 years already so it can't be used with the new (programmable) pipeline. From what I [know](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/176638-GLUT-and-OpenGL-3-2) it supports up to GL 3.1 inclusive only. The project which replaces GLUT is [FREE GLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) which is up to date and can be used both with old and new OpenGL versions. Glew is the lib that exposes the GL API for windows users. It has both deprecated and current functionality. It is up to you which to use as it mostly depends on GL version and profile type you choose. If you use compatability profile for example in OpenGL 4.0 version then you can use mix of deprecated and 4.0 API specific functionality. But if you select Core profile then using deprecated methods will not work.